# Error in http request

Tags: windows-phone-7, http, http-status-code-302

I'm making a http request to google.com. This is the way I'm doing it:

```
    HttpTestWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/");
    HttpTestWebRequest.Method = "GET";
    HttpTestWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(GetHttpTestResponse, HttpTestWebRequest);

...

private void GetHttpTestResponse(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
    WebResponse response =((HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState).EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
    ...
}
```

With fiddler it gives me a http 302 moved status code, but in the app it throws me an exception and don't redirects to the new location of the website.

Any ideas why this is happening?

**Update 1**

Im getting a `NullReferenceException`.

The stack trace is:

> at System.Net.Browser.HttpWebRequestHelper.RemoveHttpOnlyCookies(Uri requestUri, String setCookieHeaderValue)
>     at System.Net.Browser.HttpWebRequestHelper.ParseHeaders(Uri requestUri, SecurityCriticalDataForMultipleGetAndSet`1 headers, WebHeaderCollection collection, Boolean removeHttpOnlyCookies, HttpStatusCode& status, String& statusDescription)
>     at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.Progress(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>     at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
>     at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)

Comment: What exception are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `HttpTestWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;`

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be some specific HTTP header (google seems to send some duplicate cookie headers) on the landing page (http://www.google.com) which is causing this! Other sites/pages seem to load ok.